# Flask custom ValidationError doesn't surface error

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, validationerror

I'm working my way through Miguel Grinberg's awesome [flask mega tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) and am struggling to figure out why I don't see any errors in my browser, terminal, or log file when a form fails a custom validation rule.

### Here is the form class:

```py
    class EditProfileForm(FlaskForm):
      username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
      about_me = TextAreaField('About me', validators=[Length(min=0, max=140)])
      submit = SubmitField('Submit')
    
      def __init__(self, original_username, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.original_username = original_username
      
      def validate_username(self, username):
        if username.data != self.original_username:
          user = User.query.filter_by(username=self.username.data).first()
          if user is not None:
            print("There should be a validation error here")
            raise ValidationError('Please choose a different username.')
```

As you can see, I'm printing to the console to confirm the validator is being executed, and the conditionals are met. I DO see "There should be a validation error here" in the console, but the validation error isn't actually raised.

### Here is the route for this form:

```py
    @app.route('/edit_profile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    @login_required
    def edit_profile():
      form = EditProfileForm(current_user.username)
      if form.validate_on_submit():
        current_user.username = form.username.data
        current_user.about_me = form.about_me.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your changes have been saved.')
      elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.username.data = current_user.username
        form.about_me.data = current_user.about_me
      return render_template('edit_profile.html', title='Edit Profile', form=form)
```

I've got another form class with a custom validator that is very similar, and the ValidationError it raises works perfectly. Here's what that other class looks like...

### Class with working ValidationError:

```py
    class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
      username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
      email = EmailField('E-mail address', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
      password = PasswordField('Password', 
        validators=[EqualTo('password_confirm', message='Passwords must match')])
      password_confirm = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
      submit = SubmitField('Register Account')
    
      def validate_username(self, username):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user is not None:
          raise ValidationError('Please use a different username.')
      
      def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user is not None:
          raise ValidationError('Please use a different email address.')
```

Thanks for reading my question!

Comment: Try clearing your cache and reload the `EditProfile` page

Comment: @GitauHarrison I tried clearing my cache, and another browser too. No change in behavior (i.e. purposefully causing the validation to fail doesn't surface an error).

Comment: Please share a link to your project so I can look at it

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being my form template - I made the mistakes of iterating through "errors" rather than "form.username.errors". I thought this wasn't the issue because the errors were correctly surfacing on the page to create a new user - but that is a different page (which is obvious, in retrospect...).

Incorrect template:

```html
    {% for error in errors %}
    <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
    {% endfor %}
```

Corrected template:

```html
      {% for error in form.username.errors %}
      <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
      {% endfor %}
```